# Apple subscription or in-app purchase not working in store version - inApp-products details not displaying or getting

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, app-store, applepay

Last week we have submitted an App that had in-app purchase for one product. The app & in-app product got approved and got a mail from the apple. Then We tried to subscribe to the product, but we are not able to purchase the same.
The same product is working in development, ad-hoc and test flight. Searched regarding the same and found that some times it may correct in 2days. But it not happened in our case. So we approached the AppStore helpdesk and gave the details as requested by them.

Answer (score 0):

In between we are checked more about such issues and found that in our app it's no listing in the information area of the App in Appstore, other apps having inApp is showing the details there. So we again informed the screenShots to apple support which showing the inApp details.[image: Sample inApp Information from Appstore]

We also found some interesting [answers](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/13324?page=2) which may help with the same issue.
So finally they have corrected the same and worked the inApp purchase.